# Can the PGI compilers output the generated Cuda code to a file

Tags: cuda, openacc, pgi

I would like the generated CUDA code to be saved in a file for examination.  Is this possible with OpenAcc and PGI compilers?

Answer (score 3):

You should be able to pass `-ta=nvidia,keepgpu,keepptx` to any of the PGI GPU compilers, which will retain the intermediate code emitted by the toolchain during the build.

Also refer to the command line help, e.g.:

```
pgcc -help
```

Note that PGI compilers have moved to a more integrated toolchain recently, which eliminates the generation of CUDA C intermediate source files, so the above approach works but gives you intermediate files that are not C code (they are llvm and ptx).  If you want CUDA C intermediate code, you can also add the `nollvm` option:

```
-ta=nvidia,keepgpu,keepptx,nollvm
```

The "kept" files will generally have `.gpu` and `.h` extensions for llvm/CUDA C code, and `.ptx` extension for [PTX](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/parallel-thread-execution/index.html#abstract).